# WebClient throws SocketException (Invalid argument)

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I use the code below in an attempt to create a file to an ftp server. However i get a socket exception. Can anyone help me solve this exception? Same issue seem to happen when I use the `UploadFile(uri, filepath)` function.

I tried with setting the credentials as `NetworkCredentials` too in the options of WebClient but getting the same result.

Got the same result on a remote ftp server too.

Im using .NET 4.7.1

```
byte[] xmlBytes = XmlDocumentToByteArray(xml);

WebClient webclient = new WebClient() {
    Proxy = null
};

Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://test:test@localhost/test.xml");
//Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://localhost/test.xml");
webclient.UploadData(uri, xmlBytes);
```

Exception:
(In english: An invalid argument was supplied)

```
System.Net.WebException: Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven
   bij System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   bij System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   bij System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   bij System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   bij System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   bij System.Net.FtpWebRequest.QueueOrCreateConnection()
   bij System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(Boolean async)
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   bij System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data)
   bij System.Net.WebClient.UploadData(Uri address, Byte[] data)
   bij ProbeOrderPlacement.Order.OrderSubmit.SubmitOrder(XmlDocument xml) in H:\VSWorkspace\VSTS\Quantore\Probe\ProbeOrderPlacement\Order\OrderPlacement.cs:regel 28
```

Also tried the following code, but it trows the same exception (but on `.GetRequestStream()`)

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://127.0.0.1/test.xml"));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Proxy = null;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");
request.ContentLength = xmlBytes.Length;

//Upload the data
using(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    requestStream.Write(xmlBytes, 0, xmlBytes.Length);
}
```

Exeption:
(In english: An invalid argument was supplied)

```
System.Net.WebException: Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Er is een ongeldig argument opgegeven
   bij System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
   bij System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   bij System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   bij System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   bij System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   bij System.Net.FtpWebRequest.QueueOrCreateConnection()
   bij System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(Boolean async)
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   bij ProbeOrderPlacement.Order.OrderSubmit.SubmitOrder(XmlDocument xml)
```

Comment: @mjwills An invalid argument was supplied. Updated my question too.

Comment: The exception doesn't match the code. The exception complains about `System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String fileName)`. Post the *actual* code that produces this exception. Post the full exception text as well, not just the call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. The full exception will contain status codes and inner exceptions that explain what the invalid argument is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the function `UploadFile()`  generates almost the same error, but updated the exception message with the `toString()` text. Still don't see details about the invalid argument though.

Comment: If you want people to help, post the *actual* code and  corresponding *full* exception.

Comment: I did post the full exception the `toString()` method returns on the trown exception as you requested. The provided code the actual code used. If you want a more detailed exception please explain how.

Comment: This is a very low-level mishap, nothing to do with the arguments you passed since they don't get used until later.  The underlying OS function (WSASocket) failed, seemingly unhappy about creating a TCP socket.  That should never happen of course.  But crap happens with networking code, there is always far too much junk hanging off a socket that professes to keep your machine safe and running smoothly.  Disable the installed anti-malware product first, any kind of firewall and whatnot next.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, this actually helped me find the problem. It seems that the problem was that I was running the application from a Network drive. When i created a repository locally all went well. If you can post it as an answer I can grant you the bounty.

Comment: I can't answer this correctly without knowing the actual malware that caused this mishap.  Such a detail is very important to future victims.  Please create your own post to share what you discovered and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that. Answered my own question, but would love to assign the bounty to you. If you provide any kind of answer I will do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this comment by Hans Passant

> This is a very low-level mishap, nothing to do with the arguments you passed since they don't get used until later. The underlying OS function (WSASocket) failed, seemingly unhappy about creating a TCP socket. That should never happen of course. But crap happens with networking code, there is always far too much junk hanging off a socket that professes to keep your machine safe and running smoothly. Disable the installed anti-malware product first, any kind of firewall and whatnot next.

I figured out that for my case the problem was the fact that I had the repository of my solution on a Network drive my company provides me. My best guess is that the upload failed due to underlying security measures although I didn't dig into it deep enough to be able to prove this was the case.

Creating a new local repository on my c drive overcame the issue.

So advice for feature readers that experience the same thing, would be to look at the underlying infrastructure to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [WebClient.UploadFile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2).Second argument is file name.There is no overload for `byte[]`

try this

```
webclient.UploadData(uri, xmlfilename);
```

Comment: You're right, but that would be a compiler error, not a runtime error. That means the OP didn't provide a [mcve], and that your answer won't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: `UploadData` does accept `byte[]` for the second parameter. I think you've accidentally taken a look at the documentation for `UploadFile` (as linked).

Comment: it Returns
Byte[]
A Byte array containing the body of the response from the resource.There is no overload for byte[]

Comment: @AzarShaikh You linked the `UploadFile()` documentation. I tried this function too (with an absolute path to a file) but it trows the same error. `UploadData()` accepts `byte[]`.

Comment: @MarkBaijens one more try webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("******", "*********");webclient.UploadFile("ftp://yourftp", "filename");

Comment: @AzarShaikh As I stated in my question, I already tried that too.

Comment: sorry i missed it

Answer (score 0):

Your ftp url seems to be wrong. Change your code to

```
byte[] xmlBytes = XmlDocumentToByteArray(xml);
WebClient webclient = new WebClient
{
      Proxy = null,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test")
};

Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://localhost/test.xml");
webclient.UploadData(uri, xmlBytes);
```

Comment: I tried this approach too, mentioned it in my question. It gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code as-is except one change (reading XML file and converting it to `byte[]`) and I was able to upload the file without any problem.

[image]

Since you have not shared your XML structure or the method you are using to read and convert XML into `byte[]`, I went with *simplest form of XML* and the *out-of-the-box method in `.NET`* to read and convert the file data into `byte[]`.

Here is the XML text from source.xml file:

```
<System>
    <E01></E01>
    <E02></E02>
    <E03></E03>
</System>
```

Here is my code to read-convert-upload source.xml on ftp server:

```
        byte[] xmlBytes = File.ReadAllBytes ("D:\\source.xml");

        WebClient webclient = new WebClient ()
        {
            Proxy = null
        };

        Uri uri = new Uri ("ftp://ftp_user:ftp_password@localhost/test.xml");
        //Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://localhost/test.xml");
        webclient.UploadData (uri, xmlBytes);
```

> **NOTE:** This is a Winforms application build on .NET Framework 4.7.1

If you have any specific requirement in terms of XML structure or the way you need to read the file, you can share the same and we can discuss this further.

Alternatively, you can share a trimmed-down version of your solution on Github for others the troubleshoot.

Hope this helps!